# How do I get a specific dependency with grab?

Tags: groovy

Im using the AWS SDK:

```
@Grab(group='com.amazonaws', module='aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk', version='1.11.232')

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.*
import com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.DescribeEnvironmentsRequest
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider

class testAws {
    static Object test (){

        def awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials('sdfsdfdf', 'sdfsdfdsf')
        def ebClient = new AWSElasticBeanstalkClientBuilder()
            .withRegion(Regions.valueOf('US-EAST-1'))
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider (awsCreds))
            .build()

        ebClient.describeEnvironments(
            new DescribeEnvironmentsRequest().withEnvironmentNames('zzzzz')
        ).getEnvironments()
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V`
```

Doing some googling i found the aws sdk depends on a specific version of the http library. If this was a java project I would define that specific version in my pom or gradle config. How do I do this with grab?

To be clear I dont need to grab http explicitly because it gets pulled in as a dependency of the aws sdk. The problem is I have a different (newer) version installed locally. Even if I explicitly grab the older version it still throws this error. If I uninstall the new version from my system it works. But I want to enforce this in groovy and not have to modify local environemnt.

Comment: Add a `@Grab` line for that library as well? I feel I'm missing the question

Comment: that doesn't seem to work. ill add that to the question